# In PowerBuilder, how to set byte[] to null?

Tags: nullable, powerbuilder

I am calling data  from .dll, I need to have NULL to skip some cases.

```
int Fn(ref byte xpara[])
setnull(xpara)
```

The code above gave me an error and setnull() doesn't work for byte[]

Since the data from .dll might have 0s in it, I am using byte[] to avoid stopping by 0. I still need to set a byte[] to null in some cases.

Comment: Please show the actual PB code you used (the code in your question isn't valid), and why my proposed answer "doesn't work out".

Answer (score 1):

No matter the datatype, you cannot use SetNull on a structure or array.

To reset an array, define another variable that you never add any entries and assign it to the one needing to be reset.

String ls_files[], ls_empty[]

ls_files = ls_empty

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an array type to Null in PowerBuilder*.  The best you can do is to reinitialize the array argument to a local `byte[]` variable that hasn't been assigned.

```
function integer Fn(ref byte xpara[]);

   byte l_null[]

   // zero-out the referenced byte array
   xpara = l_null

   return 1

end function
```

Then you can check the length of the reference argument from the caller (i.e.:  `UpperBound(byteArray)`.

* You ***can*** set it to null, but the caller would end up with a null object error if it tried to do anything (eg: `byteArray[1] = 1`) with it.

Comment: Thank you, though the local variable method actually doesn't work out.

Comment: How is it that it "actually doesn't work out"?  Can you edit your post and show the code you're using?